# use on div at a time using $_SESSION

Tags: php

I want to use one div at a time using an echo and $_SESSION. When I put this on the web it only shows $form. Can you see if I'm doing anything wrong?

```
    $signedIn ='<h3 id="throughHeader"> Account options</h3><br/>
        <p id="throughP"> <a href="convenientaccountinfo.php> Account Info </a></p><br/>
        <p id="throughP"><a href="convenientaddaddress.php> Add Address </a></p><br/>
        <p id="throughP"> <a href="convenientaddcreditcard.php> Add C. Card </a></p><br/>
        <p id="throughP"> <a href="convenientsignout.php> Sign Out </a></p>';


        $form='<form id="signInForm" method="POST" action=""><h3 id="formHeader">Sign Into Account</h3><br/>
        <p id="pRegister"><a id="register" href="convenientregisterpage.php"> Register </a></p><br/>
        <label>Email Addr:</label><input type="text" name="userEmail" id="email" size="15"/><br/>
        <label>Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="15"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign In" id="formSubmit" name="submit"/> </form>';

    $username = $_SESSION['userEmail'];
    if(!$username){
        $signedInForm="$form";
    }
    else{
        $signedInForm="$signedIn";
    }
}
```

This is the form POST with validating until it sets the $_SESSION. Thanks for looking at it again.

```
 $email=$_POST['userEmail'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(empty($email) || empty($password)){
    $msg_to_user3="Fill in both fields";
    }
    else{
    $results=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE userEmail='$email'");
   if (mysql_num_rows($results)==0)
       $msg_to_user3 ="No such User";
    else
    {
      while ($login_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
      {
       $password_db = $login_row['password'];
       if ($password!=$password_db){
         $msg_to_user3 ="Password doesn't match";
       }
         if ($password_db!=$password){

        $msg_to_user2="<a id='forgetpassword' href='convenientforgotpassword.php'>Forget Password</a>";
     }
       else
       {
          $active = $login_row['active'];
          $userEmail = $login_row['userEmail'];
          if ($active==0){
             $msg_to_user3= "Activate account at ($userEmail) </p>";
      }
         else
          { 
           $_SESSION['userEmail']=$username;//assign session
      }

      }
      }
    }
       }
}   
<html>
    <body>
    <div id="formSignIn">
        <?php echo $signedInForm ;?>
        </div>
    </body>
    </htmo>
```

Comment: Did you call `session_start()` at the start of this script? Also, please don't quote simple variables. Just use them as is `$signedInForm = $form;` not `$signedInForm = "$form";`

Comment: Ok I'll put that into use with quotes. Yes session_start() is at top of page.

Comment: Could it be that $form is in a <form> and the action is sending it to the same page? Should I have another page for the $signedIn variable?

Comment: You need to debug the contents of `$_SESSION['userEmail']` We can't see where or how you set it, but it always seems to contain a null or false value.

Comment: Ok I put the code for setting the $_SESSION. Maybe thats the problem.

Comment: I got the $_SESSION to work but now the <h3> in $signedIn is only showing. Can anyone see why that is happening?

Comment: Is this your real full code? You didn't close the `?>` before `<html>`

Comment: You have four `<p>`s that all have the same `id` attribute. `id` needs to be unique, that may be why you only see the `<h3>`.

Comment: Ok thanks for all the help but one more thing. The <h3> is showing and two of the <p>s the address and sign out. Is there a reason why that is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the $_SESSION working which switched in between the $form and $signedIn variables. And as far as two only showing with the p s I took the ids off and in the a href the quotes weren't closed so it didn't shut each link. Thanks for all your help!!